# How can I use Retrofit to POST a complex JSON parameter

Tags: android, json, retrofit

The Post request i need to do should look like this

```
{
"project": {
    "name": "newname123",
    "identifier": "id55"},
"key":"8f583ad25100575b974062e0cee43e47aa158e4e"}
```

I was able to send it to server using raw implementation in Postman, but have no idea how to send the same using form-data

Here is my interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("projects.json")
Call<Project> CreateProject(@Field(value = "project") ProjectToSend project,
                            @Field("key") String key);
```

No matter if I tried to do it with @body or @field, it does not work.

ProjectToSend class

```
public class ProjectToSend {
private String name;
private String identifier;

public ProjectToSend(String name, String identifier) {
    this.name = name;
    this.identifier = identifier;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create two classes, to represent the complete JSON, something like this:

```
public class Project {
    private ProjectToSend project;
    private String key;

    // getters and setters
}

public class ProjectToSend {
    private String name;
    private String identifier;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and then call:

```
@POST("put/the/url/here")
Call<Project> createUser(@Body Project project);
```